# Current macro in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

The purpose of the current macro is to find a pointer to the task structure of the currently running process.

So regarding its usage when developing a kernel module,  and according to its definition does this macro return the PID of the current running user-space process or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a user-space process performs a system call, this macro points to the `task_struct` associated with this process. It doesn't only contain the `PID` of the process but a lot of other info.

Comment: So for example, if a process make a sysctl or ioctl, the macro will point to this process correct?

Comment: @HA-AS yes this is precisely its purpose.