# When we execute insmod <modulename.ko> then insmod process runs in which context userspace context or system mode context

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am new to the Linux Kernel Development.  I have some questions.

When we execute insmod  which context does the insmod process un in, user-space or system mode?

How to use current macro in user space C program or do we have alternative to traverse the kernel task_struct structure?

Comment: Hi, just an FYI, in the future please limit a question post to a single question, it makes both the question and answer cleaner and more useful in the future.

Answer (score 4):

`insmod` itself is a user-space program or a symbolic link to a user-space program (on Fedora 21 `insmod` is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/kmod`).  It runs as a user-space application just like any other application.  What makes `insmod` special is that it makes the [`init_module`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/init_module) system call.  `init_module` is what actually going to load the module into the kernel.

With regards to your second question the `current` macro is only defined in the kernel.  You can find more detail at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616628/current-macro-in-linux-kernel).